# Doing a post request on golang for uber authentication not working

Tags: google-app-engine, go, uber-api

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request when doing a request do oauth on uber API. I was successful in doing redirection. But when trying to do oauth, it fails. Here's how I've set up my code.

```
type UberRequest struct {
    ClientSecret string `json:"client_secret"`
    ClientId     string `json:"client_id"`
    GrantType    string `json:"grant_type"`
    RedirectURI  string `json:"redirect_uri"`
    Code         string `json:"code"`
}

func HandlerUberAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
   c := appengine.NewContext(r)
   AuthorizationCode := r.URL.Query().Get("code")

   client := urlfetch.Client(c)

   uberRequestForm := &UberRequest{
       ClientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
       ClientId:     CLIENT_ID,
       GrantType:    "authorization_code",
       RedirectURI:  URI_REDIRECT,
       Code:         CODE,
   }

   uberRequestFormJson, _ := json.Marshal(uberRequestForm)
   req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", UberTokenHost, strings.NewReader(string(uberRequestFormJson)))
   req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
}
```

Also, if you're interested in looking at the golang code via playground - here it is https://play.golang.org/p/o8EtgudiMR

I know that my client secret and other information works as I've tested in on postman, I don't know why it fails on google app engine.

Comment: `req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", UberTokenHost, strings.NewReader(string(uberRequestFormJson)))` looks suspect. How does Uber want you to supply the data? As a JSON body? Should be bytes, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

- The [authorization and authentication documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication) doesn't mention anything about JSON.
- The request to the [GET https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize)
   endpoint requires you to send the parameters in the query string of the URL using the GET HTTP method, **not** in the body of the HTTP request.
- Make sure to [URL/percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) each parameter you are sending.